# How to write simple map-reduce job for converting tab separated text file into sequence file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I want to take a text file as input to mapper and output a sequence file. How to write a simple map-reduce jobs for the same? text file will have tab separated values.
Eg input: group1  1 2 3 4 5
For such input i would like to create output sequence file which will have "group1" at its key and its value should be a vector of 1 2 3 4 5.

How can I write these jobs?
Also I feel I don't need a reducer in this case. How to write an identity reducer job in this case? Can I skip writing reducer job?

Appreciate any help. 
Regards.

Comment: You don't even need Hadoop -- are you sure you have enough data to make it worth the hassle?

Comment: At this moment the data is not that large, but once everything is working it will be run on large dataset. Anyways this is been solved. I simply wrote just a map function for this. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can skip writing a `Reducer`. Set this to simply `Reducer.class`. Also call `setNumReduceTasks(0)`. Your `Mapper` should use `TextInputFormat` and take `Long`, `Text` as key/value input. The `Text`is the line. Break it up however you want and output the key/value as, say, `Text` and `Text`. Specify `SequenceFileOutputFormat` to write sequence files.

I still don't know why you'd want to do this, but that's how you do this.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks for the answer! I just wanted to create a simple sequence file given a text file. I am using Naive Bayesian algorithm using Hadoop for which the input file must be in Sequence file format.

Comment: Well, "sequence file" isn't one format. It's kind of like saying "the input needs to be in XML". It's a container format. It most certainly has to be a sequence *with the keys and values exactly as expected by the reader*. If this is Mahout, it is certainly not what you are outputting here.